# Maybe getting a viewPager to initialize one tab at a time?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-databinding

I am using TabLayout, [Android DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) and [Binding-Collection-Adapter](https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter) (all lib versions latest to date) together inside a `support fragment` to achieve something like:

- x number of tabs depending upon `List<ModelType> listItemModels`
- the item view is using android binding as well and has a root view having 2-3 independent layouts 1 of which has visibility set to `GONE` and is visible depending upon a condition in the `itemModel`

The issue I am facing is if suppose there are 4 tabs and this conditional view which is supposed to be visible only on the 4th tab is also visible (but with apparently no data as expected) on the 3rd tab making the view show some space where the conditional view is supposed to be shown.

I tracked down that it's happening because of the next view/anonymous child fragment is initialized in advance(sort of lazy loaded) and to a method which could've been helpful `setoffscreenPageLimit()` but the default min value is `1` and can't be set to zero as per the API docs.

How can we fix this? I would stay away from a full re-implementation away from android databinding. 
Has anyone else binded a tablayout before? with individual itemmodel binded as well?

Comment: I solved this problem by creating different fragments for each tab

Comment: @masoudvali but that would mean that we giveup on android databinding for the tabs/viewpager etc. Binding inside those fragments can be preserved though.

Comment: yes I know. but there is no option as far as i know. I did search a lot but i didn't find anything